# Error while creating Entities with Doctrine in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to create entities but I have an error, the entity is created in the project but nothing created in the database.

Here is the error message:
[image: error message]

and this is the generated Class

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
*/
class Category
{
    /**
        * @ORM\Id()
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    */
    private $id;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

and this is my doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
   dbal:
    # configure these for your database server

    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '8.0.18'
    charset: utf8mb4
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 3306
    user: 'root'
    password: 'root'
    dbname: 'omega'
    #   dbname: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
```

Comment: Can you please post an entity?

Comment: Can you please post your config/packages/doctrine.yaml ?

Comment: @Clarity edited

Comment: @shaax i have edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this at the end of your doctrine.yaml :

```
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Then retry. Let us know.

Comment: It worked in the project thank you so much, but still the problem in the database because it wasn't created as in the project, am I missing something ?